# Permutation on $\omega$ and Ramsey ultrafilter

Tags: set-theory, ultrafilters

let $\pi:\omega\to\omega$ be permutation and $\mathcal{F}$ is <strike>Ramsey</strike> selective ultrafilter on $\omega$. There are uncountable many increasing subsequences of $\pi$. Can one proof that one of them  has domain in $\mathcal{F}$ ?

Comment: Assuming that "growing" means monotonically increasing, the answer is yes. The Ramsey property implies that, on some set in $\mathcal F$, $\pi$ will be either increasing or decreasing. But there is no infinite decreasing sequence in $\omega$, so "increasing" is the only possibility.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. "growing" == "increasing". But how to proof the fact ?

Comment: I don't think anyone had a problem with growing. The problem is that it's unclear by what you mean a sequence here. Do you mean an infinite set of natural numbers with increasingly larger images? Or what?

Comment: @ar.grig: define a coloring $f: [\omega]^2 \to 2$ such that for $i<j$, f(i,j)=0 if $\pi(i)<\pi(j)$, otherwise it gets $1$. By the Ramsey property, there is a large set such that $f$ is monochromatic restricted on the set. It must then be 0.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: yes, you are right. Permutation $\pi$ is clearly sequence of natural numbers. The subsequence is restriction of $\pi$ on some infinite subset of $\omega$. And this restriction must be monotonically increasing.

Comment: @JingZhang: thank you. If I have truly  understood, you are pointing to fact that the ultrafilter is selective iff every partition of $[\omega]^2$ into two pieces has a homogeneous set in ultrafilter [Kunen]. I have read about it right now in  Andreas Blass's article "Ultrafilters on Countable
Sets". But there is neither proof nor link. Can you give me the link where this material clearly explained?

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Thank you. Please, provide the link where things are clearly explained. I am reading your article "Ultrafilters on Countable Sets" right now. But there is neither proof nor link there.

Comment: I'm not sure what remains to be explained. Just apply the definition of "Ramsey ultrafilter" to the partition of $[\omega]^2$ into the pairs that remain in the same order when you apply $\pi$ and the pairs whose order is reversed by $\pi$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Sorry. I am new to ultrafilters. And it is not obvious for me why this two definitions of selective ultrafilter are equivalent: "Every partition of $[\omega]^2$ into two pieces has a homogeneous set in ultrafilter" and "Every partition of ω into sets not in ultrafilter admits a selector in ultrafilter". Your article "Ultrafilters on Countable Sets" is too brief for me. I am asking about more detailed text.

Comment: The best detailed text on ultrafliters is the book "Theory of ultrafilters" by Comfort and Negrepontis.  The specific result, relating selective to Ramsey, is due to Kunen and was published in David Booth's thesis; I think the title is "Ultrafilters on countable sets" and it's in one of the early volumes of the Annals of Mathematical Logic, but I don't have time to check right now.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: I have found and read David Booth's thesis "Ultrafilters on a countable set".  When Booth proves Kunen's theorem (4.9, page 20),  he mostly omits  proving of "selective implies Ramsey" with phrase:   "The proof can be closely patterned upon a popular proof of Ramsey's theorem". May be you know where to get full proof. I have tried standard Ramsey proof but something went wrong.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Oh, finally it seems to become clear after reading Comfort and Negrepontis book. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AndreasBlass and @JingZhang for the answer.    First of all saying "Ramsey ultrafilter" I meant "Every partition of $\omega$ into sets not in ultrafilter   admits a selector in ultrafilter". So-defined ultrafilter better to be called selective.  And Ramsey ultrafilter can be defined as follows  "Every partition of $[\omega]^2$ into two pieces has a homogeneous set in ultrafilter".  This two definitions are eqivalent, so termins "Ramsey" and "selective" are used as synonyms in literature,  which led me to some misunderstanding. If we know that this two definitions are equivalent,   the answer is trivial, what was noted by @AndreasBlass and @JingZhang.

But proof of equivalence is not trivial in part "selective" $\implies$ "Ramsey".
Proof can be found in the book "Theory of ultrafilters" by Comfort and Negrepontis cited by @AndreasBlass.

Comment: While the proof of "selective implies Ramsey" is not trivial, it is quite straightforward to prove (assuming CH) that Ramsey ultrafilters exist, so that (since the implication "Ramsey implies selective" *is* trivial) at least *some* selective ultrafilters are Ramsey.